# How to create multiple login options using bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

How can we create options for multiple authentication options using Bluemix Mobile Client Access. For eg facebook, google and custom.
Currently I'm able to provide only 1 method.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are only able to provide 1 method of authentication when using the Mobile Client Access service. Apologies for the inconvenience.